# CentOS bridge not passing traffic to eth1?

Tags: networking, centos, bridge

I'm setting up a network bridge on CentOS 6.4 and I'm not able to pass icmp or tcp traffic via eth1. UDP traffic looks fine. 
I'm sure that my test host is cabled to eth1 correctly. My config files look like the following and iptables are disabled.

I've done this dozens of times before without issues; I'm at a loss. What am I missing?

*/etc/sysctl.conf*

```
...
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.proxy_arp =  1
...
```

*/etc/sysconfig/ifcfg-br0*

```
DEVICE=br0
TYPE=Bridge
ONBOOT=YES
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.20.254
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.20.1
DNS1=192.168.100.80
```

*/etc/sysconfig/ifcfg-eth0*

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGE=br0
HWADDR=00:0C:29:ED:C7:71
```

*/etc/sysconfig/ifcfg-eth1*

```
DEVICE=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGE=br0
HWADDR=00:0C:29:ED:C7:7B
```

Comment: What does `brctl show` give?

Comment: @Nils it was fine. Just figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urgh.. I'm doing this in a virtual environment. I just forgot to set the two vSwitches to allow promiscuous traffic. Once I turned that on everything else is working as it should.

Comment: Where were the vSwitches in this environment?

Comment: @Nils - connected to both Eth1 and Eth0. This specific bridge is for monitoring and testing in high latency environments.

Comment: I still do not get it. eth0 and eth1 are connected to other virtual devices (for latency simulation) and these devices had to be set to promisc mode?